# Finite/algebraic extensions of rational functions

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, rational-functions

I'm looking for results on the subject of finite/algebraic extensions of rational functions, but I only find papers who deal with algebraic geometry. I only know the basis of Galois theory. Could you give me the main results on this subject and, if you could, links (or references) ?

Comment: Search on "function fields".

Comment: Yes, I've searched this but I found nothing of my level.

Comment: When you write "rational fractions", do you mean "rational functions"? And what kind of result are you looking for?

Comment: Yes, I mean rational functions. I'm looking results like "for every n, there is an algebraic (or even Galois) extension of degree n". I assume that it depends on the ground field.

Comment: So, you have a field, $k$, and the field $K=k(t)$ of rational functions with coefficients in $k$. Then $x^n-t$ is irreducible over $K$ and of degree $n$, so there's your extension of degree $n$.

Comment: Oh, and if $k$ contains all the nth roots of unity, this extension is Galois, isn't it ? But how can we prove that the polynomial is irreducible ?

Comment: You're considering finite extensions of $k(t)$ for a field $k$. If $k = \mathbb{F}_p$, then there is class field theory for function fields.